# All 1D lines overlap each other

Tags: algorithms

I want to verify the correctness of this algorithm.

Problem: given a list of intervals, where the first index is greater than the second, determine if every interval overlaps with every other interval.

Examples

```
----
  ----
True


--------
  --
  -
True


----
    ---
False


-----
 ---
-
False, 3rd line does not overlap with second
```

This Typescript solution finds the maximum start and minimum end of all intervals. Then it checks that every interval overlaps the max start and min end.

```
const overlaps = ([min1, max1]: [number, number], [min2, max2]: [number, number]): boolean => {
    const overlapDist = Math.max(0, Math.min(max1, max2) - Math.max(min1, min2))
    return overlapDist > 0
} 

export const allOverlap = (intervals: [number, number][]): boolean => {
    const [maxStart, minEnd] = intervals.reduce(([maxStart, minEnd], [start, end]) => {
        const ms = (start > maxStart) ? start : maxStart
        const me = (end < minEnd) ? end : minEnd
        return [ms, me]

    }, [-Infinity, Infinity])

    if (minEnd < maxStart)
        return false

    for (const interval of intervals) {
        if (!overlaps([maxStart, minEnd], interval))
            return false
    }

    return true
}
```

From my tests, this seems to work. However, I am unsure how to prove its correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I_{max}$ be the interval with max_start and $I_{min}$ be the interval with min_end.

**Statement:** All intervals overlap each other if and only if all intervals contain max_start and min_end

**Proof: (<-)** This direction is easy. If all intervals contain max_start and min_end, then they all overlap each other at max_start and min_end.

**(->)** (Using Contraposition)  Suppose some interval $I$ does not contain max_start. We also know that start time of $I$ is smaller than max_start. It means that it will not overlap with $I_{max}$ since it will end earlier than $I_{max}$. Similarly, you can show that if an interval does not contain min_end, it will not overlap with $I_{min}$.

Comment: The <- direction is actually a bit more tricky: you have to show that also $max\_start\le min\_end$. Its not hard to prove this, but I think its important

Comment: @nirshahar Thanks for going through the answer. But I did not understand why $max \_start \leq min\_end$ is required?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Looking again at your answer - I think I was confused why we need both $max\_start$ and $min\_end$. Which for some reason made me assume you stated that the intervals overlap iff they overlap the entire interval $[max\_start, min\_end]$. In this case, this interval would be empty if $max\_start > min\_end$

Comment: @nirshahar I think having $max\_start$ or $min\_end$ is also sufficient.